# How to find a custom selector inside a web element using X-path or other method?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, css-selectors

I am working on a web scraper on Python using selenium and I want to scrape a specific element (`data-car-id`) from a div which I can actually locate using the Xpath

[image: The id I want to scrape]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must find the element using whatever method you would like, `xpath`, `id`, `class_name`, etc. Next, just use the `.get_attribute` method, it should look like this:

```
element = browse.find_element_by_class_name("listing-item")
element.get_attribute('data-car-id')
```

Comment: I knew the first part but the second one ... litteraly been 2-3h tryng to get arround it, thank you so much!!